# Using NLTK Library in Iron Python

Tags: python, nltk, iron

I am trying to use NLTK library and importing it using Iron Python. I am not able to get that done and an error is reported saying that the library is not found. Please do let me know what could be the problem. I am a beginner in python and looking to use NLTK with Iron Python and C#.

I have NLTK libraries installed using the windows msi installer and when I import them in IDLE (Python 2.7) they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/24357?ProjectName=ironpython) issue in the codeplex of ironpython can help you.